# query works, nothing happens

Tags: php, sql, crud

Ok, I have changed the code to two different querys and cut the `GET_$ID` semicolon and place it like the isset `POST` variables.
Now I get two new errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: edit in C:\wamp64\www\projekt\edit.php on line 20
>   "$ID = $_GET['edit'];  "
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: title in C:\wamp64\www\projekt\edit.php on line 23
>    "SET title='$title'"  "ID = $ID"

So something is lost from the `ID` or `POST`.
I have dumped all the values so they exist, is there something wrong with the syntax?

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    // input array
    if (isset($_POST['title']) 
        && isset($_POST['director'])
        && isset($_POST['year'])
        && isset($_POST['genre']) 
        && isset($_GET['edit']))

        // filter txt input
        $title = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'title',FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);

    $director = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'director',FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $year = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'year',FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    $category = $_POST['genre'];

    $ID = $_GET['edit'];  

    // Edit query 
    $sql = "UPDATE movies 
            SET title='$title' director='$director' year='$year' 
            WHERE ID='$ID'";

    $insert = mysqli_insert_id($conn);

    $insert = "UPDATE category 
                SET category='$category'
                WHERE ID='$ID'";

    if ($conn->query($sql) &&  $conn->query($insert) === TRUE) {
        echo "<div class='receipt'>Record ".$ID." updated successfully<br>
              <a href='index.php'>Gå tillbaka</a> </div>";
    } else {
        echo "Fel vid anslutning : " . $conn->error;
    }  
} $conn->close();
```

Comment: are you confused why table `category` only is being updated?

Comment: You're overwriting your first `$sql` query (where you update the movie info) with your second assignment (where you update the category).  And, generally speaking, this is a good illustration of why basic debugging techniques are necessary.  If things aren't working as you think they should, try to follow the values... `echo` them at certain points, use `var_dump()`, etc.  Your IDE is just an editor.. it doesn't run your code.

Comment: use different variable for the query (ex: $sql and $sql1)

Comment: I have dumped all the values.

Comment: Tag this question with correct database type

Comment: @spillresist give us form input's

Comment: I've added white space to your code so you can see what it's doing. Take a look at your second `IF`. You've omitted the curly braces so only the NEXT line is affected by it. I can't imagine that that was your intention.

Comment: Also, unrelated, you should 100% switch to binding your SQL parameters using prepared statements. Your `UPDATE` statement is wide open for SQL injection.